# CSS How to adjust banner image to whole page?

Tags: html, css, image, path

here is a link to my repo 
[trevormolano.bitbucket.io](http://trevormolano.bitbucket.io)

I need to create [image: Template Website]

I am having issues trying to create the banner. How do I re-size it so it extends to the whole page? I tried using background-image for CSS as well, but it doesn't work well at all. It showed up as a sliver on the top. I have been messing around trying to get it to work, but here it what I have so far:

```
<header>
  <!-- // Logo / Banner -->
  <a href="index.html"><img src="images/cycleWorld.png" alt="CycleWorld Logo" id="logo"></a>
  <div id="bannerbox">
    <img src="images/banner.jpg" id="banner"/>
  </div>
  <!-- Logo / Banner // -->
  <nav>
    <!-- // Navigation Bar -->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
      <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a> </li>
      <li><a href="clubevents.html">Club Events</a> </li>
      <li><a href="">Blog</a> </li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a> </li>
      <li><a href="">My Cart</a> </li>
    </ul>
  <!-- Navigation Bar // -->
  </nav>
</header>
```

But I want to not have the image on the HTML, I want to add it with CSS.

Comment: You want to have the image inside the `bannerbox` ? If so you need to set up a `height` to the `#bannerbox` and use `background-image: url(images/banner.jpg);`

Comment: I was just seeing if i needed a div with an id to adjust the size of the element the banner is in.

The main issue i am having is that the image is not showing up at all.

Comment: Where are you serving the image from? Have you checked the image path? Are you using some server?

Comment: I am using it locally. 
It works when I use content property.

Comment: As a sanity check, try updating your bitbucket repo page to my answer and test it there. When I wrote the answer I tested it directly there and it worked for me. If it works there is a path problem.

Comment: Updated the answer so can test it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the image form the HTML and refactor the `#bannerbox` in your `css`:

```
#bannerbox {
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 60vh; 
/*  ^^ set this to the desire height in whatever unit px, etc. */
    background-image: url(../images/banner.jpg); 
/* ^^ check the path to the image, depends how you are serving your site*/
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Remember you are calling the `background-image` from your css not your html and since the image location is `images/banner.jpg` and your css is `css/home.css` when calling from the css you will need to go up a folder and then inside the images folder. But **once online** you can directly call `background-image: url(/images/banner.jpg);` because the `/` is the root of your site.